# CITAR EL NOMBRE DE VARIABLES DINAMICAS EN CICLO FOR

Tags: r, bucle-for

Tengo el siguiente `dataframe` (peso) con varias columnas (variables) (en realidad tiene mas de 50 variables, pero este ejemplo ilustra la misma idea)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero añadirle una nueva variable llamada pondera (peso$pondera) que realice una función matemática para la variable valor 1, por ejemplo `5*Valor1/pi`, lo mismo haga para las otras variables y luego me sume el total. Suena sencillo, pero el detalle está en que escribir o repetir el mismo codigo 50 veces o más es un poco tedioso; es decir,

```
peso$pondera <- 5*Valor1/pi + 5*Valor2/pi + 5*Valor3/pi + ...
```

Estuve pensando realizar un ciclo FOR, pero no hallo como citar el nombre de las variables de forma dinámica dentro del ciclo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema pasa por sumar un conjunto de variables por fila. con R base es bastante sencillo, suponiendo datos como estos:

```
set.seed(2020)
df <- data.frame(id=1:5, 
                 Valor1=runif(5), 
                 Valor2=runif(5), 
                 Valor3=runif(5), 
                 OtraColumna = LETTERS[1:5])

df

  id    Valor1      Valor2    Valor3 OtraColumna
1  1 0.6469028 0.067384386 0.7644140           A
2  2 0.3942258 0.129152617 0.7438358           B
3  3 0.6185018 0.393117930 0.8261657           C
4  4 0.4768911 0.002582699 0.4227291           D
5  5 0.1360972 0.620205954 0.4092877           E
```

Tu formula podría definirse como: `(Valor1+Valor2+Valor3)*5/pi`. Accediendo a las columnas por índice, puedes hacer:

```
df$pondera <- rowSums(df[2:4])*5/pi
```

O bien por Nombre:

```
df$pondera <- rowSums(df[grep("Valor",  colnames(df))])*5/pi
```

Si, tienes varios coeficientes distintos, supongamos que uno por variable, en mi ejemplo, tenemos tres Variables, por lo que tendríamos estos coeficientes:

coeficientes <- c(1,2,3)

Para multiplicar cada variable por su correspondiente coeficiente, simplemente creamos una matriz de coeficiente que repita cada fila:

```
matriz_coeficientes <- matrix(rep(coeficientes, nrow(df)), ncol=length(coeficientes), byrow = TRUE)
matriz_coeficientes

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    1    2    3
[4,]    1    2    3
[5,]    1    2    3
```

con esto es muy simple hacer lo mismo que en el ejemplo anterior:

```
df$pondera <- rowSums(df[2:4]*matriz_coeficientes)/pi
```

Comment: Buenos días Patricio te agradezco mucho tu respuesta y tu ayuda. Pero en realidad, el problema es un poco más tedioso, ya que en realidad los coeficientes que multiplican a las variables "Valor" no son los mismos (5/pi). Estos coeficientes dependen del valor de la variable (Valor n). Es decir: df$pondera= Valor1*C1+Valor2*C2+Valor3*C3+...+Valorn*Cn

Comment: Buenos días Patricio te agradezco mucho tu respuesta y tu ayuda. Pero en realidad, el problema es un poco más tedioso, ya que en realidad los coeficientes que multiplican a las variables "Valor" no son los mismos (5/pi). Estos coeficientes dependen del valor de la variable (Valor n). Es decir: df$pondera= Valor1*C1+Valor2*C2+Valor3*C3+...+Valorn*Cn

Comment: @ulpiano, entiendo, revisa mi última edición que trato de responder a tu último comentario.